# Mod_rewrite condition not working

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I've checked the regexs and they all match but for some reason its not working in mod_rewrite?

I would like

http://www.system.com/chips/intel?c=xxx

to read:

http://www.system.com/chips/intel/xxx

I have:

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (c=.*)$`
`RewriteRule (/([^/]+)/?).*?c=(.*) http://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1/$2/ [L]`

And I'm getting an error.  What's going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regular expression doesn't match that URL. As you have it:

- group 1 matches `/chips/`
- group 2 matches `chips`
- group 3 matches `xxx`

You probably want something like:

```
RewriteRule ^/([^/]+)/([^/]+)\?c=([^&]*)  http://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1/$2/$3 [R=301]
```

Comment: This is the correct regex but it still doesn't match in .htaccess.  grrrr

Comment: @frio This won't match in .htaccess. Rewrite rules in .htaccess strip the path. So if it's in the root, it would be RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)\?c=([^&]*) ...

Answer (score 0):

Don't think rewritecond get's the uri params unless you have "QSA"

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html